# How to convert ajax date and format it?

Tags: ajax

when i get value of 'MyProperty_Payment_Test_ADate' from my controller to ajax, the date value displayed as /Date(1435689000000)/, i want this in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format. how can i convert this?

```
 function SelectPaymentTest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../Payment/SelectPaymentTest',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            var tr = '';
            $(data.PaymentTestList).each(function (key, val) {
                tr += '<tr>';
                tr += '<td>' + val.MyProperty_Payment_Test_Id + '</td>';
                tr += '<td>' + val.MyProperty_Payment_Test_Name + '</td>';
                tr += '<td>' + val.MyProperty_Payment_Test_ADate + '</td>';// this contain value as "/Date(1435689000000)/"
                tr += '<td>' + val.MyProperty_Payment_Test_CDate + '</td>';
                tr += '<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" category_Id="' + val.MyProperty_Payment_Test_Id + '"  style="cursor:pointer;"></span></td>';
                tr += '<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" category_Id="' + val.MyProperty_Payment_Test_Id + '"  style="cursor:pointer;"></span></td>';
                tr += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#GemPaymentTestBody').html("");
            $('#GemPaymentTestBody').html(tr);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in object based programming the variable is use to bind with the object so first what you need create a var date and transfer your date in it now you are able to get the value from it.
var d=new Date();
now d as a Date so d.getMonth(); 
there are some basic method are available.